# Introduction to Deligne–Lusztig theory

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, characters

Where can be found some introductory notes on Deligne–Lusztig theory? Where should I start to learn this theory?

I know some representation theory found in Etingof and Baker, and some algebraic geometry.

Any recommendations are welcome.

Comment: How about Digne-Michel Representation of finite groups of Lie type. It might be way more elementary than what you are looking for.